# In azure devops, how to share environment between different project?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps Server and currently exploring YAML for deployment(replace classic release).
I've set up a self-hosted Windows machine and created an environment and resources for Project A via powershell ./config.cmd.

How can I share this environment/resource to project B in different repository, like a deployment group, to ensure that only one service runs on my self-hosted machine?

A method to share environment between projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the Pipeline Environments Resource doesn't support being shared between projects in Azure DevOps for the time being.

Currently, Azure DevOps only supports sharing Pipeline Environments to Deployment Groups of another project in **Organization Settings -> Deployment Groups**.

Result:

[image]

We are not able to share the Environment Resource to another Environment in different Project.

I can fully understand your requirement. And many users have the same requirement, you can check the following suggestion tickets:

[Share a VM Resource among different environment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/share-a-vm-resource-among-different-environment/963981)

[Shared Pipeline Environments within Projects](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/shared-pipeline-environments-within-projects/889113)

For a workaround, you can use [Self-hosted Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops) in YAML Pipeline. And Self-hosted agent can be shared between two projects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we have decided to use a self-hosted agent to share the environment.

To set up an agent,

1. create a new `agent pool`, for example, named "Deploy"
2. Set up each self-hosted agent accordingly:

> 

```
.\config.cmd --pool Deploy --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice  --work '_work' --url 'http://{{url}}' --auth Integrated
```

In the CD yaml, we use a deployment job with an environment but without resource, and it work

To specify which agent from the pool to use, we use `demands` to limit it.

```
   - deployment: ${{ parameters.EnvironmentName }}
     environment: 
       name: ${{ variables.EnvironmentName }}
     pool: 
       name: ${{ variables.DeployPoolName }}
       demands:
         - Agent.Name -equals ${{ variables.DeployAgentName }}
     strategy:
       runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - download: none
```

Comparison:

| Feature | Self-hosted Agent | Environment Agent | Deployment Pool |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Setup Command | `--pool` | `--environment` | `--deploymentpool` |
| Usage in YAML pipeline(deployment job) | Can use environment but resource | Can use environment/resource | Can't use environment/resource |
| Usage in Classic Release | Can't use | Can't use | Can use |
| Sharing Scope | within the same collection | within the same project. Can be set as deployment pool and share for other collections but only works for classic release. | within the same collection |